# How do I stop a specific video I watch in YouTube from altering my recommendations?

Tags: youtube

YouTube will display recommendations of videos based on:

- your favorites
- your liked videos
- your watched videos

Now, let's say that somebody sends me a link and it's a video for which I don't want similar being recommended.

Is there a way I can avoid recommendations based on that particular video?

So far I've been hitting dislike because, well, I don't like the videos. However, I'm not sure this is entirely effective, and on the other hand, likes and dislikes has turned into more than a personal view of a video, and more into a way of appreciating users' content. If the quality and the content of the video was good but I just don't happen to be interested, would it be fair that the user had a dislike on it? (This question is probably out of scope for the answer I'm looking for here, but I believe it helps providing context.)

Comment: Watch it while being logged out?

Comment: @Alex I pretty much try this but then you've got youtube asking you to log in to see certain videos or not able to actually like it / favorite it if you liked it, and logging in on an iOS or Android app actually throws you off the video you were watching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing your search history and watch history will stop recommending the videos

Comment: Thanks! As I understand your answer I can clear my view history for this particular video rather than all of them -- is that correct?